# How to create insert function in BST without specifying root as parameter

Tags: c++, oop, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've been given a task to create a method of Binary Search Tree class to insert elements in the correct place in the tree. The declaration of this function is:

```
void BST::insert(int k)
{   

}
```

Can someone explain why isn't a root node given as parameter ? How am i able to traverse the tree, when I do not have its root node ? Having a return type of void hints me to use the 'this' keyword

I've tried implementing the following:

```
void BST::insert(int k)    {
   while(this->root != NULL) {
        if(k < this->root->value) {
            this->root = this->root->leftChild;
        } else {
            this->root = this->root->rightChild;
        }
   }
    this->root = new node(k); 
    }
```

This is additionnal OOP code:

```
struct node {
  int value;
  node* parent;
  node* leftChild;
  node* rightChild;

  node (int);
  int dessiner(ofstream&, int);
};

class BST {
  public:
    node* root;
    BST();
    void dessiner(string);
    void swap(node*, node*);
    void inserer(int);
};
```

EDIT: I added 2 pointers. tmp to traverse tree and P to keep track of tmp's parent node

```
node* tmp = this->root;
    node* p = NULL;
    while(tmp!=NULL) { 
        p = tmp;
        if(k < tmp->value) {
            tmp = tmp->leftChild;
        } else {
            tmp = tmp->rightChild;
        }

    }

    tmp = new node(k);
    tmp->parent = p;
```

Comment: You're on the right path. Consider what using `this` means, and what is `this->root` representing. Should you change the root of the tree when inserting a new element? Should you change it always, or only some times?

Comment: `node *root;` this is the root pointer and a member of the `BST` class itself, so it doesn't need to be passed again. In your while loop, you are changing this value to do a null check and eventually making it a nullptr. Use a temp pointer for such operations.

Comment: I suppose I've made a mistake by passing the root again, and I do not want to do that. I've thought doing `node* tmp = new node()` and searching for the right place to put the new node, but the constructor for node struct needs an int as parameter obligatory? `node(int)`

Comment: `new node()` allocates memory for a new node object on the heap,  constructs a node there and returns a pointer to it. The question you should ask yourself is: Do I want to construct a *new* node to be the temp, or do you want the temp node to start from some existing node? `Node* tmp` is a pointer to a node, not some specific node. You can change where tmp points to, without changing the pointed node itself. For example: `Node* tmp = nullptr; tmp = someNode1; tmp = tmp->leftChild`

Comment: Constructor gets called only when an object is being created from that class. `node *temp = root;` is just pointer assignment and doesn't call constructor

Comment: so if I try to  `node* tmp = this->root` and use it to traverse the tree, this will not result in an error since tmp is only a pointer and not an object, thus I do not need to do `node* tmp = new node()` first ?

Comment: `this->root =` think about what happens to the *previous* `root` member value when you do that. Where do you think it went ?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to have `node *tmp = new node()` first.

Comment: I've tried redoing the code by adding a pointer to reference the parent node of the tmp node (from @WhozCraig). I've eddited my post. Although i do not think I've done it correctly

Comment: You're over-complicating this. `root` is a member of a BST instance. It hosts the root of the BST. Insertion starts there and moves on. [In short, it should look like this](https://pastebin.com/PzrAUKvq), and ideally, you should make the two argument constructor overload for `node` (the value, and the parent pointer) to clean that up a bit.

Comment: Thank you, @WhozCraig, your code snippet works as intended. Can I just ask why are you doing `**pp = &root;` instead of `*pp = root` ? **pp takes an address which I understand by using &, in the second, root is a pointer as well ?

Comment: @NikolaStoilov You can change a thing through a pointer to that thing. You need to set the appropriate child pointer to point to your new node.

Comment: @NikolaStoilov That's just one mechanism for walking a pointer chain. I prefer because it's efficient and lets you walk the pointers in the structure. As in, the actual pointer members; not just their values. There are other ways to do it. Get some paper, draw boxes, arrows, and arrows to arrows in that code's case. Work through it one line at a time; ideally single stepping in a debugger. it will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain why isn't a root node given as parameter ?

It is. `BST::insert` implicitly has a `BST *` parameter, named `this`. From there you can get at `root`. Note that you don't need `this->` to refer to `root`, it is implicit in body of the member function.

> Having a return type of void hints me to use the 'this' keyword

The return type has nothing to do with it.

Note that you will need to assign the new node to `p`'s `leftChild` or `rightChild`, after `insert` finishes, nothing points to it.

Comment: I'm using tmp ptr stock root's address, and pointer 'p' to keep track of tmp's parent node. Currently I'm trying to figure out differences between the EDIT code and the proposed one from the comments. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with BSTs I usually write a public function like the one you have which calls a the private, recursive function with the root of the tree. You don't have access to the root of the tree from outside the class so it doesn't make sense for the public function to accept anything more than the element to insert.

```cpp
void BST::insert(int k)
{   
  insert(k, root);
}

void BST::insert(int k, node* curr)
{   
  // logic to insert the new element
  ...
}
```

You can combine these functions with a default parameter so from outside the class you can call `bst.insert(5)` and `curr` will start out as the root of the tree.

```cpp
void BST::insert(int k, node* curr = root)
{   
  // logic to insert the new element
  ...
}
```